# S-matrix and it's exponential form

Tags: quantum-field-theory, s-matrix-theory

By using [Dyson series](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dyson_series) for the representation of the $S$-matrix, it's expression can be written in a form
$$
\hat {S}(\infty , -\infty) = \sum_{n = 0}^{\infty}\frac{(-i)^{n}}{n!}\int \limits_{-\infty}^{\infty}d^{4}x_{1}...\int \limits_{-\infty}^{\infty}d^{4}x_{n}\hat {P}(\hat {\Gamma }_{i}(x_{1}))...\hat {\Gamma}_{i}(x_{n})), \qquad (.1)
$$
where
$$
\hat {N}(\hat {H}_{k}(t_{i}), \hat {H}_{k}(t_{j})) = \left\{ \begin{matrix} \hat {H}_{k}(t_{i}) \hat {H}_{k}(t_{j}), t_{i} > t_{j}  \\  \hat {H}_{k}(t_{j}) \hat {H}_{k}(t_{i}), t_{j} > t_{i} \end{matrix}\right. .
$$
How to rewrite $(.1)$ into exponential form?

Comment: You exchange the time ordering $\hat{P}$ with the integrals and recognize that the integrand is a power of $\int d^4x \hat{\Gamma}(x).$

Comment: See also [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Perturbation_theory_%28quantum_mechanics%29#Method_of_Dyson_series).